# phpBB in a subfolder behind nginx

Tags: nginx, phpbb, phpbb3

I am trying to deploy a phpBB forum behind a load balancer that will distribute the traffic:

- If `https://example.com/forum/*`, redirect to **instance A** (phpbb + nginx)
- Any other path on `https://example.com/`, redirect to instance B (other stuff)

Therefore, I want to have phpBB installed on **instance A** and available under `https://example.com/forum/`.

On instance A, I am running nginx. Here's my *nginx.config* (with the important stuff only):

```
http {
    server {
        listen [::]:443 http2 ssl default_server;
        listen      443 http2 ssl default_server;
        server_name example.com;

        # PHP BB
        root /var/www/mysite/forum/src;

        # fastcgi
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/fastcgi-php.conf;

        location /forum {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            rewrite ^/forum/(.*) /$1 break;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite_app;
        }

        location ~ \.php(/|$) {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php$is_args$args;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        }

        location @rewrite_app {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my problems:

- When I visit `https://example.com/forum/` the forum loads but all internal links are written without the `/forum/` path, making the load balancer redirect to instance B.
- When I visit `https://example.com/forum/index.php`, internal links are written correctly with the `/forum/` path, but I get a phpBB application 404 `The page is not found`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I think that you "location /forum" is relative to a root like /var/www/mysite/forum/src/forum and i don't think that is this what you want.

Comment: Indeed it's not what I want. I'd like to serve `/forum` out of `/var/www/mysite/forum/src` without having to change my folder architecture.

Comment: take a look at the alias and root directive in nginx 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias